# what does generalized estimating equations with robust standard error mean

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, standard-error, sandwich

I am currently working on logistic regression and came across some articles stating "**generalized estimating equations with robust standard error**" or "**with robust sandwich estimators for variance**". Can someone please tell me what these mean?

Below is how I run my logistic regression. I am not sure if R already took care of those error calculations. If not, what associated R code I should run in order to have this included in my analysis?

```
model <- glm (disease ~ prescore, data = mydata, family=binomial)
```

Comment: No, by default, `glm` or `summary(model)` will not calculate robust sandwich standard errors. You would have to use another package, for example `sandwich` and `lmtest`. Then, you could write `coeftest(model, vcov = sandwich)` or something like this.

Comment: Thank you for the input! Do you know how I can get an odds ratio & 95% CI? I know how to get those values without sandwich errors ```exp(cbind(OR = coef(model), confint(model)))``` but I can't seem to incorporate the ```coeftest``` and ```vcov``` into this code.

Comment: Use the `coefci()` function from `lmtest()` to get confidence intervals. You can supply the functions used to construct the standard errors (e.g., `sandwich::vcovHC`) to its `vcov.` argument.

Comment: @Noah Thank you!! How about odds ratio or p-value? Can you pls put those together (odds ratio, CI, and p-value) for me? I am still a bit confused..

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do this using the `lalonde` dataset in `cobalt`, where `treat` is a binary variable.

```r
data("lalonde", package = "cobalt")

fit <- glm(treat ~ age + educ, data = lalonde, family = binomial)
est <- lmtest::coeftest(fit, vcov. = sandwich::vcovHC)

#Coefficient estimates and CIs
cbind(est, confint(est))
#>                 Estimate  Std. Error    z value   Pr(>|z|)       2.5 %
#> (Intercept) -0.266058710 0.424816044 -0.6262916 0.53112371 -1.09868286
#> age         -0.023963432 0.008351086 -2.8694987 0.00411123 -0.04033126
#> educ         0.006699987 0.031100402  0.2154309 0.82943139 -0.05425568
#>                   97.5 %
#> (Intercept)  0.566565436
#> age         -0.007595603
#> educ         0.067655654

#Odds ratios and CIs
exp(cbind(est[,1], confint(est)))
#>                           2.5 %    97.5 %
#> (Intercept) 0.7663941 0.3333098 1.7622042
#> age         0.9763214 0.9604712 0.9924332
#> educ        1.0067225 0.9471899 1.0699968
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here I used HC3 robust SEs as implemented in `vcovHC()` in the `sandwich` package. `lmtest::coeftest()` provides a nice interface to incorporate the robust standard errors, and you can use `confint()` on its output to extract the Wald confidence intervals. Alternatively, you could have used `lmtest::coefci(fit, vcov. = sandwich::vcovHC)` to get the confidence intervals directly.

To get the odds ratios and their confidence intervals, I exponentiated the coefficients stored in the first column of `est` and their confidence intervals. It's not appropriate to exponentiate the standard errors.

Comment: This is very useful! I noticed there was no p-value in the output. If I want to report p-values, can you pls show me the R code for it?

Comment: The p-value is in the column `Pr(>|z|)`.